# Single Vagrantfile for OS X and Windows

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile

We are using vagrant across our team so we can build up identical dev environments. While it works great most of the time, we have come across some issues specific to the host OS, be it OS X or Windows, e.g. when using synced folders the `nfs => false, :nfs_version => 3` options need to change.

Is there a recommended way to deal with this? Should the Vagrantfile first detect the host environment and then proceed accordingly? As we use it more and more, I don't want cases where one developer has issues specific to Vagrant/Windows and so changes the Vagrantfile, pushing up his changes, then a developed on OS X pulls this amended Vagrantfile and it doesn't work right, so he makes changes relevant to his system etc.

Answer (score 5):

The `Vagrantfile` is just ruby, so you can easily insert a condition that depends on the host OS:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  # ...

  if RUBY_PLATFORM =~ /darwin/
    config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", type: "nfs"
  else
    # ...
  end
end
```

Comment: Should we be concerned about `RUBY_VERSION` on JRuby?  Does/has/will Vagrant ever run on JRuby?